# Custom footnote breaks

Tags: page-breaking, footnotes

Does anybody have an idea how I could get custom footnote breaks like "if the footnote is longer than *x* lines, then break it to the next page"?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx)

Answer (score 3):

I don't know any way to do it on footnote base. But you can set the maximum height the footnotes can ocupy on the page:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
abc\footnote{\lipsum[1-3]}

\newpage
\dimen\footins=8\baselineskip\relax
abc\footnote{\lipsum[1-3]}

\newpage abc\newpage
\dimen\footins=20\baselineskip\relax
abc\footnote{\lipsum[1-3]}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks Ulrike, something like this was exactly what I am looking for.